# Do you have genetic algorithm in production?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, production, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

Is it good idea to use genetic algorithm in production?

If you are using it:
In what case?
What pros for selecting subj?
Can you easily add changes to algorithm?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538235/what-problems-have-you-solved-using-genetic-algorithms-genetic-programming

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304580/have-you-ever-used-a-genetic-algorithm-in-real-world-applications is probably a closer match.

Comment: The content of the question is more about qualities, problems and advices than about examples of actual implementation. (true the header implies something else)

Comment: If you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. If you know Genetic Algorithms (GAs), every problem should not be solved with it.

Answer (score 3):

A typical scenario is to use GA as a search tool to find some 'innovative' design that improves some pre-existing man-made solution to given problems.

Once such a solution is found it can very well be used in 'production', or even mass production in the case of hardware manufacturing (just think that the first application ever of GA has been implemented as an optimization of design for aeronautic parts).

Also - talking about software that makes real-time use of GAs - in case of GA driven machine learning (there's a chapter on that on [David E. Goldberg's GA bible](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Genetic-Algorithms-Optimization-Machine-Learning/dp/0201157675/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1269814473&sr=8-2)), genetic algorithms will go 'live' and represent indeed the adaptive engine of the solver in question.

Comment: Summary: I was flagged because I accidentally used a short url for an amazon link (I shorten all my links by default, didn't know I was depriving SO of revenue). I told him he was an ass for flagging me as it would've been sufficient just to point out that I should not to shorten the link and I would've edited the post. At this point he told me I was an ass back (not sure why) and I told him he was being a dick, and asked him to please stop.