# What are the current problems yet to be solved in Genetic Algorithms?"

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Currently I was studying the genetic algorithm and I got it very interesting area to work in but as per my new field I am not getting any idea about the topic. So I want to know that "What are the current problems yet to be solved in Genetic Algorithms?".
Thanks!

PS: I read the concepts and still working to improve knowledge in it still ideas and problems are most welcomed.

Comment: Interesting question, I fear a bit too broad.

Comment: Actually this question is a rather perfect duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304580/have-you-ever-used-a-genetic-algorithm-in-real-world-applications?rq=1

Comment: Consider the opposite: "What problems *can* be solved [well] by Genetic Algorithms?" Then the set resulting from AllProblems - ProblemsSolveableWithGA will be your answer. It will be pretty darn big, though.

Comment: @miku thanks! but do you have any idea that what are the problems we can solve by GA?

Comment: @SatishPatel, this is quite funny: http://boxcar2d.com/, and this: http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

Comment: @user2246674 thanks for correcting me. That's what exactly I'm looking for. Actually as I'm totally new in at the topic so I thought to interact with some experienced people here.
So can you specify some of the problem that we can use GA to optimize.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I personally think you should rephrase your question to "What are the current problems yet to be solved in Genetic Algorithms?".

In regards to your answer, I'm also studying Genetic Algorithms (GA) and I can't say I'm an an expert, however there some of the things that plagues GAs:

- **finding the absolute optimal** when searching through an **in-complete search space**. If you need to guarantee absolute best, it is best to user other methods.
- Then there is the **encoding problem**, there are many problems where you can't really encode your problem into a GA.
- Defining a sound **evaluation function**, how you define **the best**.
- Converging in a **dynamic environment**, GA assumes the environment or search landscape is *static*
- Perform poorly with Boolean evaluation functions (Yes/No, On/Off functions)

For more information of what problems are hard for GAs is this paper, ["What Makes a Problem Hard for a Genetic Algorithm? Some Anomalous Results and Their Explanation"](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mm/Forrest-Mitchell-ML.pdf)

As for applications of GA, the list is huge, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_genetic_algorithm_applications)

Answer (score -3):

1.study The problem
2.analysis the problem
3.make possible steps to draw flow chart
4.draw flowchart
5.end

Comment: Welcome! 1) the question you're posting an answer to is *nine years old* and, based on current site guidelines, off-topic. 2) What you posted isn't an answer; it reads as a condescending reply to a question about building software. Not really a great "first action" to take with your new account...